# Best practice for structuring libraries to be required in node.js

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, require

I have several utility libraries which contain helper functions and I want to load them in order they can be used from the controllers and I'm wondering 
what is the best practice for coding utility libraries in node.

I'm little bit confused because there are several ways to do it and I'm not sure what is the best/more suitable/more reliable. Here are 2 options but I'm wondering if they are the best (for example I've seen snippets that use `module.exports = exports = function(){}`, etc)

//option1.js

---

```
"use strict";

module.exports =  function(){

     exports.test1 =  function(){ console.log('hi I'm test1')};
     exports.test2 =  function(){ console.log('hi I'm test2')};
     return exports;
};
```

//option2.js

```
"use strict";

module.exports =  {

     test1 : function(){ console.log('soy test1')},
     test2 :  function(){ console.log('soy test2')}

};
```

//test_controller.js

```
/* Requiring helpers in different ways */
var option1 = require('./option1.js')();
var option2 = require('./option2.js');
```

Comment: Note that the accepted answer and this question are pretty old, and JS has updated import/export statements that improve performance and readability that are not addressed in the current accepted answer as of this writing.

Comment: @KyleBaker can you provide an example?

Comment: I don't have the time right now to write out an answer that would satisfy my standards. However, MDN has examples. An in depth exploration is currently available here: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think of my files in 3 sections:

## Section 1: CommonJS Dependencies

```
var lib1 = require("lib1");
var lib2 = require("lib2");
```

You don't need any additional wrapper functions. All node modules are [automatically wrapped](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/6bd922fce83d505e44ee3706df9a78c0ad449d64/src/node.js#L800) by node.js in a function and doing so has no benefits and just adds clutter

## Section 2: Plain JavaScript Code

This should be almost exclusively functions with a sprinkling of supporting variables or top level module code if needed.

```
var MY_CONST = 42;

function helper1() {
    //excellent code here
}

function helper2() {
    //excellent code here
}
```

Keep section 2 pure JS. Don't use commonJS idioms in this middle "pure" section. Don't use `module`, `exports`, `require`, etc. This is just my personal guideline as JS itself is stable but packaging in to modules is still under a lot of change and it's better to keep the CommonJS bits that are extraneous and likely to change separate from the interesting bits of code. ECMAScript 6 modules are most likely to replace CommonJS in a few years, so make this easier on yourself by keeping section 2 pure ECMAScript 5 and making an "CommonJS Sandwich™" as I like to call it.

## Section 3: CommonJS exports

```
exports.helper1 = helper1;
exports.helper2 = helper2;
```

- Putting all your exports at the end also gives you a quick way to understand what your public API is and prevents accidentally exporting properties due to a careless copy/paste.
- I prefer the above `exports.foo = foo;` syntax as opposed to assigning `module.exports` to a new object literal. I find this avoids the trailing comma issue with the last property of an object literal.
- Doing anything else with your `require` or `exports` statements is almost certainly unnecessary and needlessly slick or magic. Until you get to be advanced, don't do anything fancy here. (even then, if you're not TJ Holowaychuk, you're probably just being silly)

## What should I export

### A single function (@substack style)

```
function degreesToRadians(degrees) {}

module.exports = degreesToRadians;
```

Keep it small and simple.

### An object of functions

If your module is a set of helper functions, you should export an object containing those functions as properties

```
var foo = require("foo");

function doubleFoo(value) {
  return foo(value) * 2;
}

function tripleFoo(value) {
  return foo(value) * 3;
}

exports.doubleFoo = doubleFoo;
exports.tripleFoo = tripleFoo;
```

### A Constructor Function

If your module is a class design for object-oriented use, export the constructor function

```
function GoCart() {
  this.wheels = 4;
}

GoCart.prototype.drive = function drive() {
  //vroom vroom
}

module.exports = GoCart;
```

### A Factory/Config Closure Function

Once you have mastered the above 2 patterns (really!) and feel confident exporting a factory function that takes options and maybe does some other dynamic stuff, go for it, but when in doubt, stick with the first 2, simpler choices.

```
//do-stuff.js
function doStuff(howFast, what) {
   return "I am doing " + what + " at speed " + howFast;
}

function setup(options) {
  //The object returned by this will have closure access to options
  //for its entire lifetime
  return {doStuff: doStuff.bind(null, options.howFast)};
}

module.exports = setup;
```

So you could use that like

```
var doStuff = require("./do-stuff")({howFast: "blazing speed"});
console.log(doStuff.doStuff("jogging"));
//"I am doing jogging at speed blazing speed"
```

Comment: Excellent answer @Peter. Very useful for module design. I'll keep in mind your recommendations. Please would you be so kind to provide and example/link about "exporting a factory function that takes options and maybe does some other dynamic stuff". I'm interested in applying more architecture techniques to my node.js code.

Comment: This answer is out of date, as it does not address the superior new export/import syntax. It's still good information, but it is incomplete, and there are performance advantages to the new syntax (as well, arguably, as readability improvements).

Comment: Uh, as of node v6 the export/import syntax is still not supported. We're talking about non-transpiled node.js here, not ES2015 in general.

Comment: upvoted what is your opinion about exporting module.exports = (a, b) => {return a + b} meaning arrow functions

Comment: I would avoid that. I like to keep commonjs syntax separate from actual implementation code. Also named functions make for better stack traces so it helps with debugging to name them.

Answer (score 2):

For stateless utility libraries, *option2.js* is the way to go because there is no need for the code in `module.exports` to be executed every time you `require`, which is what happens when you call `require('./option1.js')()` to use *option1.js*.

If on the other hand, your modules exposed constructors that created objects that held state, then you would want *option1.js*.  For example,

person.js:

```
module.exports = function(firstName,lastName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
};
```

and then to use it:

```
var Person = require("./person");

var person1 = new Person("Foo","Bar");
var person2 = new Person("Joe","Shmoe");
```

The other advantage of *option1.js* (as demonstrated above) is that it lets you pass parameters into the module.

Comment: Thanks @go-oleg. Very interesting comments about use cases and performance :)